# Log4j2 Not found when using spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, log4j2

I do get an error message which suggest that logging was not found although i do have log4j2 dependency and jars are present as well as i exclude commons-logging from spring core jar. Yet something is still wrong and i do not know what?

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/orderlybilling]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/orderlybilling]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
```

And this is part of the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You should exclude "commons-logging" from all Spring dependencies.
And Why do you have both log4j and slf4j ?

Comment: @BeshoyFayez yes i realized that slf4j is not neede and i removed it. I have done as you said - excluding all commons loggin from sping but stil the same thing

Comment: @BeshoyFayez slf4j and log4j are not mutually exclusive, **it is valid to use both** where slf4j is just the logging facade referenced by all codes, and log4j is the actual logging implementation provider

Answer (score 1):

There is a [commons logging bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jcl/) that you want to use for commons logging which extends `org/apache/commons/logging/Log` and bridges into log4j2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This bridge still didn't solve the issue, but thanks :)

Comment: You also need to add back commons-logging. Then the bridge will route logging calls to the log4j2 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the ever confusing world of logging in Java!

First of all your stack trace by no mean indicates log4j2 is missing, but commons-logging instead (org/apache/commons/logging/Log is a type from commons-logging package). And indeed it's missing because you explicitly exclude it, yet something in your code is looking for it.

So maybe the question should be: should anything in your code be looking for commons-logging? What logging facade / implementation you actually wanted to use?

Comment: Yeah it is quite confusing :(. I never really had to set up log4j before, i just was using one for each project - but since its a new project its requires setup and it drives me "£$"%^$^&"!! hehe... Anyway i looked and on where in the code i specify that "you should look for commons" but everywhere is log4j instead